# Where is my data file?

Tags: android, file

I have an Application that requires a data file.  I connect my device to the PC with the USB cable.  I copy the application over to a directory called Aps, that I made, and my data file to a directory called data/net.me.myapp/data.  After I disconnect the USB cable, I can "Install Aps" and get my application on the device.  I cannot find the data.  I have looked with a File explorer and cannot  fine either of the directories that I made.  How can i get to my data or how should I be doing this.  My application works fine on the emulator, but I know where I am putting the data file.
Thanks

Comment: Do you know that your question is [linked](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) in the official Android documentation?

Comment: @rekire Well the link you supplied goes to "Parsing XML Data" and I am not sure what this has to do with my question.  But thanks for the note.

Comment: Look at XML at *Analyze the Feed* section and you will understand @rekire

Comment: @rekire Glad I'm not the only one that decided to look it up :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out.  When you use the USB to push a file over to the device it goes into a directory called "tflash".  Once I found this directory the rest was easy.  So for my device the full path is

```
"/mnt/sdcard" from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
+ "/tflash/Android/data" + my file name
```